# How to merge 2 queries which check for same flag columns but different value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 query which i used to fetch sum of values based on flag value

```
SELECT SUM(stock_deliveries.stockValue) AS stockValues1
FROM `stock_deliveries`
LEFT JOIN `delivery` ON `delivery`.`pk_deliveryId`  = `stock_deliveries`.`fk_deliveryId`
WHERE `stock_deliveries`.`fk_stockID` = '189'
AND `delivery`.`delivery_completed` = '1'

SELECT SUM(stock_deliveries.stockValue) AS stockValues2
FROM `stock_deliveries`
LEFT JOIN `delivery` ON `delivery`.`pk_deliveryId`  = `stock_deliveries`.`fk_deliveryId`
WHERE `stock_deliveries`.`fk_stockID` = '189'
AND `delivery`.`delivery_completed` = '0
```

Is it possible to merge this 2 query in single query ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single query with the help of [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

```
SELECT SUM(stock_deliveries.stockValue) AS stockValues, `delivery`.`delivery_completed` as deliveryCompleted
FROM `stock_deliveries`
LEFT JOIN `delivery` ON `delivery`.`pk_deliveryId` =  `stock_deliveries`.`fk_deliveryId`
WHERE `stock_deliveries`.`fk_stockID` = '189'
GROUP BY `delivery`.`delivery_completed`;
```

Doing so you will have a row for every value of `delivery_completed` with the associated sum (if you need only 0 and 1 values you can add to the where clause `and delivery.delivery_completed IN (0,1)`).
Example:

```
stockValues    deliveryCompleted
       1000           0
        700           1
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'd use conditional aggregation (i.e. `CASE WHEN` inside an aggregation function like `SUM`):

```
select
  sum(case when d.delivery_completed = 0 then sd.stockvalue end) as stockvalues0,
  sum(case when d.delivery_completed = 1 then sd.stockvalue end) as stockvalues1
from stock_deliveries sd
left join delivery d on d.pk_deliveryid = sd.fk_deliveryid
where sd.fk_stockid = 189;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @Thorsten Kettner , i need to merge the above query along with the conditional checks also `delivery`.`delivery_completed` = '0 and `delivery`.`delivery_completed` = '1' .

Comment: Sorry, I don't undderstand what you are saying.

Comment: In the above 2 query which i wrote there is an conditional check delivery_completed = 0 for stockvalues0 and delivery_completed = 1 for stock_values1 , i need this 2 conditional checks also included in the query , anyway thanks i got the answer using group by :) than you

Comment: Ah, okay. I probably didn't understand, because the conditional checks do exists in my query, only that my query selects the two values in two columns, whereas lyisia's query selects them in two rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "if" inside sum to check if you need the value in `stockValues1` or `stockValues0`

```
SELECT SUM(IF(d.delivery_completed = 1, sd.stockValue, 0)) AS stockValues1, SUM(IF(d.delivery_completed = 0, sd.stockValue, 0)) AS stockValues2
FROM stock_deliveries sd
LEFT JOIN delivery d ON d.pk_deliveryId  = sd.fk_deliveryId
WHERE sd.fk_stockID = '189'
AND (d.delivery_completed = 1 OR d.delivery_completed = 0)
```

obviously if "delivery_completed" is only 1 or 0, you can omit the last `AND` in the query ;)

Edit: as Thorsten Kettner answered you can also use case-when syntax, with only one "case" they are substantially equivalent. The `if` syntax in this case is more concise, but if you have more options is more flexible, for instance:

```
SELECT CASE sometable 
       WHEN 'top' THEN 'high' 
       WHEN 'center' THEN 'medium' 
       ELSE 'low' 
       END AS position
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION ALL` operator to keep the logic of 2 result rows but these are now in the same result instead of 2 separated